# Non-hierarchical Faceted Sparql query

Tags: rdf, sparql

What is the best way to make a facets query in SPARQL?

Id'like to build this query dynamicaly depending on previous facets selection. 
Get the N most represented values for a given list of predicates.

For now i'am using a single query for each facet which is clearly not the best way on large datasets.

Here is an example:

```
#Facets corresponding to dc:title
SELECT ?o (count(?s) as ?count ) (str(<dc:title>) as ?uri)                  
WHERE{

  # Here come the prefiltering statements from previous facets selection
  # ?s dc:format "Book" .   

  # Retrieve all values for a given facet type 
  ?s dc:title ?o .

} GROUP BY ?o ORDER BY DESC(?count) LIMIT 8
```

**Update:**

Here a working example of a combined query for multiple facets/predicates whitout prefiltering.

```
SELECT ?count ?o ?uri WHERE { 
{
   SELECT ?o (count(?s) as ?count ) (str(<dcterms:title>) as ?uri)                  
   WHERE{  

      # Retrieve all values for a given facet type 
      ?s dcterms:title ?o .

   } GROUP BY ?o ORDER BY DESC(?count) LIMIT 8

}
UNION
{
   SELECT ?o (count(?s) as ?count ) (str(<dcterms:format>) as ?uri)                  
   WHERE{  

      # Retrieve all values for a given facet type 
      ?s dcterms:format ?o .

   } GROUP BY ?o ORDER BY DESC(?count) LIMIT 8

}}
```

This query is fast and works, but if I add a statement to reflect the previously selected facet, request time increase anormaly.

Comment: I think you're asking a good question, but it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking for (I don't know if "faceted" is quite a standard term here).  Are you asking for something like "for each property in {p1, p2, p3, …}, what are the k most frequent values?"

Comment: This is exactly what i'am asking, this kind of request is easy to do on the whole graph.

But in the case of faceted search you may have to request on a small part of the graph, in my example triples having "Book" for dc:format.

The dataset resulting of this may be very large (in my case 90% of the whole graph).  

Because of the aggregates keywords I must refilter for every queries or subqueries...

Comment: These kinds of queries are actually kind of tough in SPARQL. Can you give an example of a query where **this kind of request is easy to do on the whole graph**.  Do you mean it's easy if you're only looking at one property?  If that's the case, I agree.

Comment: I've updated my question with the working query.
By easy, I mean easly understandable and executed under 10sec. This one takes about 0.6 sec.
I know execution times depends on triplesStore (I'am using Sesame by the way) but aggregates its kind of unclear to me in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I didn't know if by "easy to do" you had something better than a `union`.  I'm not sure whether you'll be able to do better than that.  The problem is in that what you really want to be doing is grouping by property, and then ordering limiting *within* each group.  I'm not sure if you'll be able to do that.  You *might* find it easier to do the top M%, as opposed to the top N, but it still doesn't seem very easy.

Comment: A faceted search is the most used way to explore datas.
Its difficult to believe that a request language like SPARQL which is designed to explore linked data, cannot provide structures efficients enought to make faceted search.
I'am probably going to keep triplestore for storage and use an indexed search engine like solr or elastic search.
Anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: It's not hard at all to get the information that you're looking for;  it's just hard to restrict it to *just* the information that you want.  The *limiting* is the hard part.  If you just want to sort the values of a number of properties by frequency, that's *easy*, and you don't need the big union at all.  The problem is in limiting it;  you'd have to do something more along the lines of "only show values that occur at least n times", or "only show values that are at least x% of the values for property p."  If you're interested in those, I can show examples.

Comment: Yes sure I'am interested.

Comment: OK, I've added an answer.  As you can see, it's not all that hard to get *similar* kinds of results;  it's just that the particular use of **limit** is rather difficult.

Comment: I'am gonna study this, thank you again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand the question, you're trying to take a set of properties and find, for some value k, the k most frequent values for each property in the data.  I think that's actually pretty hard in SPARQL, since you'd be trying to group by (property,value) pairs, order the elements within each group by the number of triples with the given property and value, and then take the top k results from each group.  I don't think that you can do that in SPARQL.  To approximate it you'd have to run a number of queries, or run a bunch of subqueries and union their results (as you did in your example).

However, if you can abandon the need for a definite k, and can settle instead for limiting the results with a constraint like "only show values for a property that appear at least k times" or "only show values for a property that make up at least k% of the triples in which the property is used," then you can get useful results.

Suppose you've got this data, in which there are two properties, and some values for each one:

```
@prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/25056010/1281433/>

[] :p1 "a" ; :p2 "x" .
[] :p1 "a" ; :p2 "y" .
[] :p1 "a" ; :p2 "y" .
[] :p1 "b" ; :p2 "z" .
[] :p1 "b" ; :p2 "z" .
[] :p1 "c" .
```

Then you can use a query like this (probably more complicated than what you need, but I'm trying to include all the things you *might* need in it, so that you can condense it later) to get the following results:

```sql
prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/25056010/1281433/>

select ?p ?value
       (count(distinct ?s) as ?occurrences)
       (?occurrences/?np as ?percentage)
{
  values ?p { :p1 :p2 }                                    # properties to examine
  ?s ?p ?value                                             # triples with each property
  { select ?p (count(*) as ?np) { [] ?p [] } group by ?p } # total number of ?p triples
}
group by ?p ?value ?np
order by ?p desc(?percentage)
```

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| p   | value | occurrences | percentage                 |
==========================================================
| :p1 | "a"   | 3           | 0.5                        |
| :p1 | "b"   | 2           | 0.333333333333333333333333 |
| :p1 | "c"   | 1           | 0.166666666666666666666666 |
| :p2 | "y"   | 2           | 0.4                        |
| :p2 | "z"   | 2           | 0.4                        |
| :p2 | "x"   | 1           | 0.2                        |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

For each property, you get the values that it has, ordered by the frequency of the particular value.  I've shown both absolute occurrences as well as percentage, because while they'll give the same order, you can use them to filter results in different ways.  For instance, you can add `having …` to the query to restrict the results.  E.g., you can restrict the percentage:

```
having ( ?percentage > .35 )
```

```
------------------------------------------
| p   | value | occurrences | percentage |
==========================================
| :p1 | "a"   | 3           | 0.5        |
| :p2 | "y"   | 2           | 0.4        |
| :p2 | "z"   | 2           | 0.4        |
------------------------------------------
```

Alternatively, you could restrict absolute occurrences:

```
having ( ?occurrences > 1 )
```

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| p   | value | occurrences | percentage                 |
==========================================================
| :p1 | "a"   | 3           | 0.5                        |
| :p1 | "b"   | 2           | 0.333333333333333333333333 |
| :p2 | "y"   | 2           | 0.4                        |
| :p2 | "z"   | 2           | 0.4                        |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Of course, you can combine those in various ways, too, in order to include or exclude results as you see fit.  E.g., you could ask only for values that occur at least 5 times, *or* that make up at least 30 percent of the values used.  This might be useful, e.g., in properties that don't get used very much:

```
having ( ?occurrences > 5 || ?percentage > .3 )
```